# Why doesn't get-service | get-member display the members lots of times?

Tags: powershell

Noob alert! I've started looking through the intros to PowerShell, e.g. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and can't see a good description of what's going on with the early example they give of

```
get-service | get-member
```

Get-Service returns a list of objects describing running services. Fine with that. Get-Member displays information about the members on an object. Fine with that. But what causes the *list* of objects coming out of get-service to be reduced to a single object for get-member?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how Get-Member cmdlet works. It takes input object and when it is an collection, it shows output for every distinct type in that collection. Otherwise it would be redundant information and not useful output format, wouldn't it? And because Get-Service returns collection of objects of type 'ServiceController' (and only of that type), you see only one output from Get-Member.

If the source collection contains objects of different type, you will see multiple output from Get-Member. You can try cmdlet Get-ChildItems, which returns different type for files and different type for directories. So when you type `Get-ChildItem | Get-Member` (in directory where you have both directories and files), you will see members of two types.

One other thing: when you want to see members of the collection object, you must precede the collection by comma. Like this: `,(Get-Service) | Get-Member`

Comment: Thanks. The basic docs on get-member don't seem to explain that.

Comment: Yas, that's definitely missing there! Also the thing with comma usage is the tiniest thing on that MSDN doc page :)

Comment: This is not specific to get-member. This is just how all pipelining works in PowerShell.

Comment: That was the initial question: why Get-Member do not show output for every single item that was sent into it (which is expectation of what output would be). Get-Member behaves little differently as it takes into account only types and not items. Am I wrong?